# Choose more than one sample for next iteration (Bayesian Acquisition Function)

Tags: machine-learning, gaussian-process

The full enumerated space for the Gaussian process I'm working on consists of more than 100, 000 instances. To accelerate the learning process I'm using Acquisition Function guided GP, where the next data point is selected based on the computed mean and standard deviation and tuning exploration and exploitation of the data. After the next point is evaluated I have to run expensive quantum chemical calculation for that data points (which takes about 20 hrs to obtain). I can't just choose one data points after each run. What should be the best way to get 100 or more data points that will likely improve my learning process?

Comment: This is an area of current research. 

I would suggest having a read about "batch bayesian optimization" techniques. At such a scale, a good starting point might be a technique similar as described by this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.01825

Comment: This seems like an interesting paper. Thank you for the link.